# Вызвать обновление двух компонентов из одного без Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core

Есть четыре компонента: Post, PostMaker, CommentSection и CommentForm. 
Post включает в себя как раз вызов всех трех. 
CommentForm имеет метод postComment(), который отправляет данные его state, занесенные из формы, в метод контроллера C#. 
Соответственно, так как в БД занесен новый комментарий, должен обновиться CommentSection, где располагаются все комментарии к данному посту, но этого не происходит. Как вызвать обновление CommentSection и очистку формы компонента CommentForm после вызова метода из контроллера?

postComment():

```
    postComment() {
        fetch('api/comment/postnewcomment/', {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                PostId: this.state.postId,
                UserName: this.state.userName,
                Body: this.state.body
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        this.setState({ userName: "", body: "" });        

    }
```

Post:

```
    export class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            postId: this.props.match.params.postId
        };        
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <PostMaker id={this.state.postId} />
                <CommentForm postId={this.state.postId} />
                <CommentSection postId={this.state.postId} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем тут тег c#?

Comment: Ну и вы отправляете запрос на сервер и, не дожидаясь ответа от сервера, просто перегружаете страницу. Наверное надо сначала дождаться результата fetch, а потом уже перегружать

Comment: Если что, window.location.reload() это временное решение было, не заметил, что здесь с ним опубликовал. Как правильно обновить?